# How do I block all analytic websites?

Tags: dns, iptables, adblock

Recently, I have realized that doubleclick is not blocked by firefox ad blocker because google is sponsoring this add-on.

How can I properly block any google analytic and google doubleclick (or possibly any other evil from google) through linux for all browsers in OS-level?

I prefer to avoid browser based solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm. I use and have adapted their suggested hosts file for my own use. If you wish to use it, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.zip
unzip hosts.zip
```

Now, we will adapt the file somewhat to our use in Ubuntu:

```
gedit HOSTS
```

Remove entirely these lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

::1 localhost #[IPv6]
```

Save and close the text editor.

Now, we'll back up your existing hosts file:

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts  /etc/hosts.bak
```

Now, we'll append the HOSTS file you just amended to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
cat HOSTS | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for amazing response. Does it totally blind google from spying on people when reading the websites other than those which belong to Alphabet Inc.? Can analytic javascripts detect that they are banned?

Comment: It blocks many hundreds of sites beyond Google. It can be detected and appears as ad-blocking software.